# Install MySQL on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: mysql, database, django, installation, tar

I have downloaded the MySQL community server and extracted the files from the .tar file. But how do I install it? I simply cannot find a easy way to to this, or any method for that matter. Or is it already installed after `tar xvf MySQL.tar`? And also, when installing the .pkg version, shouldn't it create the files anywhere? Finally, the community server is the one used with django right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not [use homebrew to install](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/), also [check here](http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2011/2144)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are developing and testing, do you really need to use MySQL? You can use sqlite which is bundled with Python.

As Vezu suggested, the best way to get started with the *server* is to download the binary installer - the [`mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86.dmg`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=408029) file.

If you plan to use it with Python, you will also need to install MySQLdb for OSX. For that, see [this answer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=408029) for a link to steps you need to follow.

Comment: Just a question..when you install the binary version, should it create the MySQL-files somewhere, because I need to modify them? And I can't find them...

Comment: Edit /etc/my.cnf according to this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the .dmg version. It's an easier way of installing mysql, it can be a pain http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: But should the dmg create files or such, or were do the files go? Because I've tried that :/